# How to insert element one by one

Tags: javascript

I have a container span element,in this span, I have couple child span elements like:

```
<span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>d</span>
</span>
```

The previous span before the above container span is called preElement, the structure is:

```
<span>w</span>
```

What I want to do is insert all child elements in the container after preElement. The new structure should be:

```
  <span>w</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>d</span>
```

What I did is :

```
for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {

    preElement.parentNode.insertBefore(container.children[i],
            preElement.nextSibling);

    preElement = preElement.nextSibling;

}
```

Can you guys let me know why it's not correct?

Comment: What is it doing currently and how have you tried to fix that behavior?

Comment: Just use `const postElement = preElement.nextSibling;` and always use that as a reference, instead of having to update `preElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that looping through the children by index will be incorrect because `child[i]` will be removed from the list in the call to `insertBefore` resulting in skipped elements.

You can treat the children of `container` like a stack and keep popping the last child of the container and inserting it after `preElement` until empty:

```js
const [preElement, container] = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

while (container.children.length) {
  preElement.parentNode.insertBefore(
    container.children[container.children.length-1],
    preElement.nextSibling
  );
}
```

```html
<span>w</span>
<span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>d</span>
</span>
```

Or, sticking to your approach of moving `preElement` to the next sibling repeatedly:

```js
let [preElement, container] = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

while (container.children.length) {
  preElement.parentNode.insertBefore(
    container.children[0],
    preElement.nextSibling
  );

  preElement = preElement.nextSibling;
}
```

```html
<span>w</span>
<span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>d</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to insert them before the container though, not just append them

Comment: I noticed that and I'm updating.